# Orders are not getting canceled programmtically through cron in Observer.php

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, cron

I am trying to cancel the pending orders programmatically but i am not able to cancel.
My code is as follows.

```
Mage::log('Step 1',null,'pradeep.log');
$order->cancel()->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true, 'Cancel Transaction.');
Mage::log('Step 2',null,'pradeep.log');
$order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(),'Transaction ID', false);
Mage::log('Step 3',null,'pradeep.log');
$order->save();
Mage::log('Step 4',null,'pradeep.log');
```

My Log is as follows

```
Step 1
Step 2
Step 3
```

No Step 4.my code is not working after $order->save();

Edited

following is the log from my system.log

```
2015-04-10T12:30:13+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /home/xxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3941
```

Following is from the exception.log

```
2015-04-10T12:30:13+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /home/xxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3941' in /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Varien/Autoload.php(136): mageCoreErrorHandler(256, 'Some transactio...', '/home/xx...', 3941)
#1 [internal function]: __extendwareErrorHandler(256, 'Some transactio...', '/home/xx...', 3941, Array)
#2 /home/xxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(3941): trigger_error('Some transactio...', 256)
#3 [internal function]: Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->__destruct()
#4 {main}
```

***Edited on 22nd April 2015***

from my log i can also see the following log

```
2015-04-22T12:30:24+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: strpos(): Empty needle  in /home/xxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 508' in /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Varien/Autoload.php(136): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'strpos(): Empty...', '/home/xxxxx...', 508)
#1 [internal function]: __extendwareErrorHandler(2, 'strpos(): Empty...', '/home/xxxxx...', 508, Array)
#2 /home/xxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php(508): strpos('', '')
#3 /home/xxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php(555): Zend_Controller_Request_Http->setBaseUrl()
#4 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php(261): Zend_Controller_Request_Http->getBaseUrl(false)
#5 /home/xxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php(574): Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http->getBaseUrl()
#6 /home/xxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php(604): Zend_Controller_Request_Http->setBasePath()
#7 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php(246): Zend_Controller_Request_Http->getBasePath()
#8 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cookie.php(129): Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http->getBasePath()
#9 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php(90): Mage_Core_Model_Cookie->getPath()
#10 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php(168): Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->start(NULL)
#11 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->init('core', NULL)
#12 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php(42): Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract->init('core', NULL)
#13 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Session->__construct(Array)
#14 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/session', Array)
#15 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::getModel('core/session', Array)
#16 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Neo/Shippinge/Model/Observer.php(82): Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
#17 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Neo_Shippinge_Model_Observer->sales_order_save_before(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#18 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Neo_Shippinge_Model_Observer), 'sales_order_sav...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#19 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
#20 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(391): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
#21 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(2049): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeSave()
#22 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(316): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_beforeSave()
#23 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Neo/Shippinge/Model/Shippinge.php(32): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#24 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Neo/Shippinge/Model/Cron.php(91): Neo_Shippinge_Model_Shippinge->savetrack(Array)
#25 [internal function]: Neo_Shippinge_Model_Cron->updateOrderDeliverStatus(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#26 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(325): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#27 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#28 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#29 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#30 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#31 /home/xxxxx/public_html/cron.php(76): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#32 {main}
2015-04-22T12:30:24+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: strpos(): Empty needle  in /home/xxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 514' in /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Varien/Autoload.php(136): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'strpos(): Empty...', '/home/xxxxx...', 514)
#1 [internal function]: __extendwareErrorHandler(2, 'strpos(): Empty...', '/home/xxxxx...', 514, Array)
#2 /home/xxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php(514): strpos('', '')
#3 /home/xxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php(555): Zend_Controller_Request_Http->setBaseUrl()
#4 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php(261): Zend_Controller_Request_Http->getBaseUrl(false)
#5 /home/xxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php(574): Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http->getBaseUrl()
#6 /home/xxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php(604): Zend_Controller_Request_Http->setBasePath()
#7 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php(246): Zend_Controller_Request_Http->getBasePath()
#8 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cookie.php(129): Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http->getBasePath()
#9 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php(90): Mage_Core_Model_Cookie->getPath()
#10 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php(168): Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->start(NULL)
#11 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->init('core', NULL)
#12 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php(42): Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract->init('core', NULL)
#13 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Session->__construct(Array)
#14 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/session', Array)
#15 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::getModel('core/session', Array)
#16 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Neo/Shippinge/Model/Observer.php(82): Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
#17 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Neo_Shippinge_Model_Observer->sales_order_save_before(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#18 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Neo_Shippinge_Model_Observer), 'sales_order_sav...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#19 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
#20 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(391): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
#21 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(2049): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeSave()
#22 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(316): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_beforeSave()
#23 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Neo/Shippinge/Model/Shippinge.php(32): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#24 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Neo/Shippinge/Model/Cron.php(91): Neo_Shippinge_Model_Shippinge->savetrack(Array)
#25 [internal function]: Neo_Shippinge_Model_Cron->updateOrderDeliverStatus(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#26 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(325): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#27 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#28 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#29 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#30 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#31 /home/xxxxx/public_html/cron.php(76): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#32 {main}
```

Comment: Going by your exception.log, you have a third party module installed. (extendware). Which module is it have you tried disabling as well?

Comment: i tried disbling it then also i am getting same issue

Comment: I think its hard to determine your error, because in another topic I wrote, that in default magento everything is working properly. I can only offer you to disable 3rd party modules as more as you can and double check the issue.

Comment: order is getting cancled if use the same code through outside of magento

Answer (score 5):

I currently tested with the following which works fine:

```
$order->cancel();

$errorMessage = 'Some error message';

$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true, $errorMessage);

$order->save();
```

Best practice and probably a better way to see what exception is being thrown that would be more descriptive is to wrap that code in a try / catch block. So:

```
try {
    $order->cancel();
    $errorMessage = 'Some error message';
    $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true, $errorMessage);
    $order->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log($e->getMessage(),null,'pradeep.log');
}
```

If that throws an exception, it should give you a better idea of what the issue might be.

Comment: Do you know if magento throw an exception during cron task when the message appear in cron_schedule table in appropriate field?

Comment: @zhartaunik The message that appears in the cron table is the result of an exception. Why?

Answer (score 3):

**Two wise try to cancel  order**

Don't need to set order state  to cancel state using extra code 
.
`->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true, 'Cancel Transaction.');`

Because of whenever we call function of `cancel()` of sales  [`order model`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php) 
Then  magento will be  `set to  order  state to cancel using`  at function

`$this->_setState($cancelState, true, $comment)` at `registerCancellation()`.

**See function cancel:**

```
 public function cancel()
    {
        if ($this->canCancel()) {
            $this->getPayment()->cancel();
            $this->registerCancellation();

            Mage::dispatchEvent('order_cancel_after', array('order' => $this));
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

**And function registerCancellation**

```
  public function registerCancellation($comment = '', $graceful = true)
    {
        if ($this->canCancel() || $this->isPaymentReview()) {
            $cancelState = self::STATE_CANCELED;
            foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($cancelState != self::STATE_PROCESSING && $item->getQtyToRefund()) {
                    if ($item->getQtyToShip() > $item->getQtyToCancel()) {
                        $cancelState = self::STATE_PROCESSING;
                    } else {
                        $cancelState = self::STATE_COMPLETE;
                    }
                }
                $item->cancel();
            }

            .........

            $this->_setState($cancelState, true, $comment);
        } elseif (!$graceful) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order does not allow to be canceled.'));
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

But must know that `order state become cancel when all items become prepare` to cancel.
And also **do not need to use function save() to change the state as it already set .**

### Optimized code:

```
 try {
    Mage::log('Step 1',null,'pradeep.log');
    // Order cancel
    $order->cancel();
    Mage::log('Step 2',null,'pradeep.log');
    $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(),'Transaction ID', false);
    Mage::log('Step 3',null,'pradeep.log');
    // remove ordr object as cancel() already change the state
    Mage::log('Step 4',null,'pradeep.log');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log($e->getMessage(),null,'error.log');
}
```

**That why create issue when try to set order state again to cancel.For multiple time save order same order state and create  excite time and memory  execution at mysql**

Comment: Thanks for answer and explanation.I will try this answer.thanks

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: remove all cod from  try and just try  this code $order->cancel().Check the error  wil held or not

Comment: there many  be some third party  extensions which  will created the issue and suggested to  disable one by one.On those module there may be some business logic which many be created

Comment: is the issue resolved?

Comment: No.i will be checking today.

Answer (score 1):

If you look through the file `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql` you can notice that there are protected property `$_transactionLevel` and some methods which affect this property: `beginTransaction` (increase lvl by 1), `commit` (discrease lvl by 1), `rollback` (increase lvl by 1). Then on `destruct` method

```
public function __destruct()
{
    if ($this->_transactionLevel > 0) {
        trigger_error('Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Magento check your lvl and show you your error.

My advice is. For the first time determine what you have: unsuccessful commit or rollback.

Try to add to commit and rollback methods log trace stack. For example this:

```
    $e = new Exception();
    Mage::log($e->getTraceAsString(), false, 'excep.log', true);
```

or with additional params:

```
Mage::log(Mage::exception(), false, 'excep.log', true);
```

In the file /lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

```
public function commit()
{
    /* here */
    if ($this->_transactionLevel === 1) {
        $this->_debugTimer();
        parent::commit();
        $this->_debugStat(self::DEBUG_TRANSACTION, 'COMMIT');
    }
    --$this->_transactionLevel;
    /* here */
    return $this;
}

public function rollback()
{
    /* here */
    if ($this->_transactionLevel === 1) {
        $this->_debugTimer();
        parent::rollback();
        $this->_debugStat(self::DEBUG_TRANSACTION, 'ROLLBACK');
    }
    --$this->_transactionLevel;
    /* here */
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: wher should i add this above code ?

Comment: updated ...............

Comment: it is going difficult because the log file is going on increasing.since the code is on the production

Comment: Ok, firstly put something not very complicated. Determine if rollback function called or not. And then put one of the stack trace

Comment: roll back not called

Comment: Ok, please show your stack trace from commit. My idea is to look for something strange called in stack. Then try to find query and execute this query in phpMyAdmin

Comment: cron is not executing when i add log trace code

Comment: You told that you log increased. Could you take the trace from there?

Comment: previous log file is a big file i am checking the strace.may be it will take time

Comment: As I wrote early: My idea is to look for something strange called in stack. Then try to find query and execute this query in phpMyAdmin. Try to check this.